# Android, building SystemUI from source error

Tags: java, android, build, cygwin, android-source

I've tried to build only the SystemUI from Android 4.4 AOSP with cygwin.
But i get an error saying: "Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknow file"
But i haven't change anything only a few java-lines, so it's the same code as people at xda builds.

This is what the Android.mk looks like:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)


LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src) \
src/com/android/systemui/EventLogTags.logtags

LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := telephony-common

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := SystemUI
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true

LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

I can't build the apk with Eclipse, because the SystemUI uses some hidden api calls and resources.
So i get a lot of error.

I've searched for hours, without comming up with anything that help :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because the SystemUI uses some hidden api calls and resources.

Yes, that's why. You need to hack android SDK so that it contains those hidden stuff used in system apps (including SystemUI). There are 2 methods to do this:

1. The hard way - compile android SDK from sources (the sources contains the hidden api). Download them via the android sdk manager or from other sources, compile them, use them.
2. The easy way - see [this](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/). The main ideea is the following: you got 2 libraries:

   - on your pc, /path-to-android-sdk/platforms/android-x/android.jar (where x is the api level), which is the library you reference in your android projects, you it contains the "normal" sdk you usually use, without secret stuff.
   - on your device, /system/framework/framework.jar, which is the sdk library your android device use, it contains the secret stuff.

Get them, join them toghether into a new android.jar library, create a new android platform and use that platform.